# Event at the end of the document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand why this doesn't work. Explanation will be appreciated.

```
 var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var height = $(window).height();
    if (scrollTop === height ) {
        alert("end!");
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zasxe/

Comment: How about explaining what doesn't work about it so I don't have to start guessing and building jsFiddles and digging around for what might not be your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(window).height()` gives you the size of the user's viewport, not the size of the total document, which is what you most likely want. To find if the user has reached the end of the document, you've got to find the document's size, by `$(document).height()`.

Furthermore, to find if a user's reached the end of the document, using jQuery, you need to capture the `scroll` event, and see if the user's reached the bottom:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() === $(document).height()) {
        alert("end!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no event handler. That code only gets run once, when the page loads.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    // Your code here
});
```

Be aware that the code will run every time you scroll, so don't make it to heavy.

And as someone else said, there were a number of other things wrong with the code - but start with putting the handler in.